# Is there a way to centrally align a input field placeholder?

Tags: html, css, safari

Im using this code ... and it works just fine in all browser except safari. Is there some solution how to centrally align placeholder in safari ?

```
 ::-webkit-input-placeholder { text-align: center; }
 ::-moz-placeholder { text-align: center; }
 :-ms-input-placeholder { text-align: center; }
 input:-moz-placeholder { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: Hmmm..`::-webkit-input-placeholder {text-align:center;}` seems to work for me in Safari Version 6.0.5. What version are you running?

Comment: Im using 5.1.7... i know there is a problem with older browsers but i thought there is some easy fix :)

Answer (score 0):

For Safari

```
text-align: -webkit-center;
```

However, the best way to analyze the working of HTML/CSS is the Web-Inspector in Safari.